# Spring Boot runtime configuration no longer running embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm working on an application that utilizes the Spring Boot framework. I work exclusively out of [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), in which I've created a runtime configuration for Spring Boot. This configuration is IntelliJ-based and is capable of running and debugging the application utilizing the settings specified in both the project's *application.properties* and *pom.xml* files.

Up until about a week ago, my runtime configuration (upon debugging/running) launched the Spring Boot application, which in turn launched an embedded instance of Tomcat. Last week, without making any project-level setting changes, this configuration has started to run Jetty rather than Tomcat. Has anyone seen this?

Unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to share the properties or pom files in-depth, but I will point out that I have no mention of Jetty in either, <s>and the following are listed as dependencies</s>:

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: You (or someone else) must have introduced something in the config file (if not in the `pom.xml`) that is favoring Jetty instead of (the default) Tomcat. Check the dependencies, the YAML/`.properties` file(s) and the Spring version you are using. Amen the different version(s) you are using...

Comment: First of all, why do you have different version specified for both dependencies?

Comment: @DanielOlszewski, these are in fact compatible, and have been removed and re-added at various points of the project without having any effect on running the app (this would not be the case had I been strictly running from CLI). This seems to be an IntelliJ IDEA issue more than anything.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ - Thanks for the input, but again there are no traces of jetty in any of our configuration or properties files (even while performing a project-wide search for 'jetty' via grep or IntelliJ).

Comment: Furthermore, a `mvn clean` has been run before each `mvn package` upon each attempt.

Comment: @SteveBass, you have to give us more input in order to figure this out. There is no way anyone can think of all possibilities for this, it's better to narrow it down as much as possible...